# TSQL select a string, repeated N times

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way, inside a TSQL `SELECT` statement, to repeat a string literal N times, where N is in integer that I select (or calculate) from columns on a table.

What I am doing, specifically, is parsing a hierarchical tree structure into nested HTML unordered lists. So, suppose we're very deep in the tree, but the next entry is very shallow. We need to close a bunch of open `<ul>` and `<li>` tags from higher up in the tree. So what I have done (but I feel is too kludgy) is:

```
select case Depth-Next_Depth
    when -1 then ''
    when 0 then ''
    when 1 then '</ul></li>'
    when 2 then '</ul></li></ul></li>'
    when 3 then '</ul></li></ul></li></ul></li>'
    ...
    end
from MyTable
```

I know that I could create a scalar function like `ReturnClosingTags(@N int)` but I don't want to add another object to the database for this. I want it to all happen in the select statement so I don't have to further modify the DB schema.

I also know that my whole approach here (writing the code myself to parse my tree into HTML) may be harebrained, so feel free to comment with an alternative... but I am interested in the question for its own sake, so even if you say "duh just use .NET library XYZ for this" I'd like to know if there's an answer to this little SQL puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server happens to have this function built-in:  `replicate()`.

```
select replicate('</ul></li>', depth)
```

Because it returns the same type as the first argument, you might want to `cast()` the value to `varchar(8000)` or `varchar(max)` first.